# How to count number of products previously used in dataframe using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where i am given with a user Id, products and product category.
i want to make a feature for dataframe where it tells how many times that user has previously consumed this product.
user 6 has taken product 8, two times previously in last row.

```
user_id products last_used
    1   8           0     
    2   2           0       
    4   2           0
    6   8           0
    6   2           0
    1   8           1
    2   2           1
    6   8           1
    6   8           2
```

I want this last used column in my dataframe.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount):

```
df['last_used'] = df.groupby(['user_id','products'])['products'].cumcount()

print(df)
   user_id  products  last_used
0        1         8          0
1        2         2          0
2        4         2          0
3        6         8          0
4        6         2          0
5        1         8          1
6        2         2          1
7        6         8          1
8        6         8          2
```